# How do I find this variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\ln\left(\frac{mg-bv}{mg}\right)=-\frac{bt}{m}$$

Okay, so I have to find $v$, but I have no idea how to go about it because there is an $\ln$ in it.

(Also, I'm not sure on how I am supposed to tag this type of question... ._.)

Comment: Did you try exponentiating both sides..?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Do you know what $e$ is?

Comment: Yeah. I know what $\e$ is...

Comment: Okay so do you know that $e^{\ln x} = x$?

Comment: Is that what I have to do? Dang.

Comment: That's all you have to do! (Plus some basic algebra.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$\frac{mg-bv}{mg}=e^{-bt/m}$$ multiplying by $mg\ne 0$ we get $$mg-bv=mge^{-bt/m}$$ adding $bv$ and subtracting $mge^{-bt/m}$ we get $$mg(1-e^{-bt/m})=bv$$ now dividing by $$b\ne 0$$ we get $v$ $$v=\frac{mg(1-e^{-bt/m})}{b}$$
remark: if $b=0$ we have $$\ln(\frac{mg}{mg})=\ln(1)=0=-\frac{0\cdot t}{m}=0$$ and all is in order!!!
thus we can assume that $b \ne 0$

Comment: Note that the limit as $b\to 0+$ is $v=gt$.  Thus, we can remove the discontinuity and define $v(b=0)=gt$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Indeed the passage about the case b=0 is unclear. Should be mentioned the fact that when b=0 every v is a solution, plus the limit you explain.

Comment: @did Yes .., I completely agree.